# How do I organize my queries in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a base query made (Thanks Justin Cave!)

Now I have to use that query and join it to different tables and sub queries many times over to do checks against our data.  Additional queries are likely to be added in the future.  So in the end there will be maybe two dozen checks for the data and the findings will be summarized in an SSRS report.    If this were in MSSQL, I would put the results of the queries into a temp table and finally run a select on the temp table.  Doing as much research as possible I've decided that the best way would be to use the WITH clause and joining with the other temp tables and queries to get results,   then Unionize all of the queries together to get my result.   However this seems like it is going to be extremely messy and large.  I'd use Global Temporary Tables, but they seem to be frowned upon in Oracle.  Perhaps  you have a better method for modularizing and organizing this?

Per our licensing agreement we are not able to add new tables in oracle (so I am told), but we are able to add view, stored procedures and functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If materialized views are not forbidden to use, you can use them to get all the advantages of a temp table.

But unless you need results of a sub-query in several different queries, you can just use as many independent sub-queries per query as you like, and operate on them as if these were tables. Most of the time you'll have pretty decent query plans.

Also, in my eyes, using a global temp table to speed up analysis 10x is worth it — as long as you don't expose sensitive data to someone not trusted.

Comment: Thanks! To make sure I understand correctly.  I could use a few materialized views create my main queries then create a bunch of views that insert results into another materialized view.  Then select the results of the latter then drop them all?

Comment: Yes, I think this should work. If you have expensive sub-queries that you need to share between several queries, you can create m-views for these sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Roll them all up into various stored procedures and enclose them in Oracle packages.

Then you can have a package for each logic area of your application. E.g. PKG_USERS, PKG_ACCOUNTS, etc.

It is also easier to track changes because you can put these under version control and see all changes at a glance.

It works for me, hopefully it helps you...

Comment: Hello Jeffrey and thanks for your suggestion.  I'm not that familiar with packages but it seems like what I am looking for.  I'll research them some more.  Perhaps you can tell me though, will they minimize how many times the view/stored procedures will be called to make them as efficient as possible?

Comment: SP / package can contain code, but not much data. How can this replace  temp tables? Also, SPs are relatively expensive to call from within queries, and making a join in PL/SQL code using two ref cursors is usually slower than doing this join in pure SQL.

Comment: One clarification if I may. Stored procedures are not slower, in fact the opposite. Stored procedures are compiled in Oracle and therefore are faster because the RDBMS knows what it needs to do ahead of time to get the data. No parsing via the interpreter will speed up the queries or operations. 
(http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_ioug_proc.htm) 
 (http://www.smart-soft.co.uk/Oracle/oracle-performance-tuning-part6.htm) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372401/performance-of-dynamic-sql-vs-stored-procedures-on-oracle)